# How to run a tensor flow program on an amazon gpu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

(there are no stupid questions but a lot of inquisitive idiots [me] so sorry if the answer is obvious). I have a mac and I want to run a tensor flow program on a gpu. Sadly, my computer does not have the necessary sort of gpu, so I was hoping to use one of amazons. I successfully created a p2.xlarge instance, but I don't know how to actually access that gpu from my program. How does the program know to use the amazon gpu? is there some code I need to include? This is the code I currently have, meant to be used on local gpus:

```
class DeviceCellWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell):
    def __init__(self,device,cell):
        self._cell = cell
        self._device = device

    @property
    def state_size(self):
        return self._cell.state_size
    
    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return self._cell.output_size
    
    def __call__(self,inputs,state,scope=None):
        with tf.device(self._device):
            return self._cell(inputs,state,scope)

devices = ["/gpu:0]
```

so what should I replace `/gpu:0` with?

Comment: it uses GPUs automatically when available. IE `sess.run(tf.ones(1000)*2)` will do multiplication on GPU

Comment: ok, so what should I do to make the GPU available? is just running the instance sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the command `nvidia-smi` to see what processes are running on the GPU(s). You'll see something like this:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Wed May 17 15:59:12 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.55                 Driver Version: 367.55                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:07:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   33C    P0    40W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:08:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   36C    P0    39W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:0B:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   31C    P0    40W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:0C:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   32C    P0    39W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:85:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   33C    P0    40W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:86:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   31C    P0    40W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:8D:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   32C    P0    39W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You should set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=[gpu_id[,gpu_id]]` to limit a specific python process to seeing only that GPU (useful if you want to run multiple applications on different GPUs).

If you don't set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` tensorflow will consume memory on all GPUs. By default you will use one GPU if it's available, so unless you're ready to move to distributed training (and since you're asking this question, you're not ready yet), you should use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`.

When you start your tensorflow script you'll see something like this which indicates that it loaded up the GPU drivers correctly:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

Comment: nvidia-smi doesn't work... I don't think it works on macs. Lacking that, what else should I do?

Comment: when I go to system preferences --> cuda, it says no gpu detected. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: I thought we were talking about running on AWS instances? Your mac doesn't have an NVIDIA GPU right?

Comment: Correct. The Mac does not have an NVIDIA GPU. I've downloaded NVIDIA, but I still can't use the nvidia-smi command. I don't think it works on macs

Comment: Are you under the assumption that tensorflow can run on your computer and access a GPU on AWS? You will certainly need to run your code on the AWS server, as well as house your data there. These commands will only run on a system with an NVIDIA GPU on them.